# Cocos2D - CCSprite runaction not finishing with low delay

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

**Problem:** I have a CCSprite animation that uses 7 frames. It works fine when I run the action with a delay of **.04f**, however, I need to run this animation at **.02f** which causes it to completely stop about 2~3 frames into the sprite animation. Bumping it up to **.03f** gets about 4~5 frames in before the sprite freezes.

I can't post the code because there's way too much. Really I'm looking for a general idea of where to start looking. The CCSprite I'm calling the runaction on is being retained, so that doesn't seem to be the issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Okay that's weird, it works fine when testing on the iPad and iPhone at .02f, but in the simulator, the animation hangs up.

Comment: I noticed this too. I believe it has something to do with the delta time. At 60 fps delta time is 0.01666. I suspect the code for checking when it's time to change the frame never actually does so when the frame delay is too small, ie very close to a single frame's delta time.

Comment: workaround: change the frames yourself in the update method